# Download all Flickr sets/images?

Tags: iphone, photos, iphoto, flickr

We'd like to download all our Flickr photos & sets to iPhoto or just to a PC directory so we can sync our photos & sets to our iPhones (and possibly get off Flickr).  Is there a way to do this?

---

**Update**: We do have a pro account right now.

Comment: Remember that downloading the original filesize is only possible for pro accounts (not free ones). Not even your own pictures.

Comment: Ok.. we do have a pro account right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Downloadr](http://janten.com/downloadr/index.php) is pretty sweet in that it saves your tags to the EXIF data. And its specifically designed so you can backup your flickr photos.

[flickredit](http://sunkencity.org/flickredit) is a Java webstart app that also backs up your tags, so either one would work nicely for backing things up locally.

Comment: flickredit is great but it stalls when downloading all my photos. Seems to get stuck on a couple particilar photos.

Comment: I ended up FlickrDown to do the downloading.  I had issues with all the tools but I did get things working!

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of Flickr tools available out on the web, available for a variety of operating system platforms.

You might consider [Flump](http://code.google.com/p/onairbustour/wiki/flump), which was built in Adobe AIR (meaning it should work on Windows, Mac or Linux with the AIR runtime, also conveniently on that download page).

You might also be interested in checking out this list of [cool Flickr tools](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2005/03/great-flickr-tools-collection/), which was where I found Flump.

Answer (score 1):

Flump is heavy and not stable.

I would recommend on of these 2:
1.FlickrDownloadr
2.Flickr AutoDownloadr

The features are not the same, for massive download I use the 1st, for more exact needs (filter tag for example) the Flickr AutoDownloadr is better.

Answer (score 1):

i really enjoyed an adobe air app called [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr?)

Answer (score 1):

One more to [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr?), easy to set up with AIR, uses proper Flickr authorisation (not username / password) and one click to save all photos.