# How to download all my photos on Flickr account?

Tags: download, photos, flickr

I have two Flickr accounts A and B. I'd like to download all my photos on account B (without having to manually download one by one), ideally in their original sizes of course, and upload them to A.  How do i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download all Flickr sets/images?](https://superuser.com/questions/55927/download-all-flickr-sets-images)

Comment: None of the solutions in the answers in that thread currently works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download this app called [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr):

> Features:
>
> - Backup your entire photostream with a click of a button
> - Download your sets (a folder is created for every set)
> - Download photos in 4 different sizes
> - Download title, tags, description (write to photo EXIF)
> - Preview images before download
> - Resume download if connection breaks
> - Download upto 500 photos in batches from:
>     → Your photostream (also search within your photostream)
>     → Your favorites
>     → Any Flickr group
>     → Explored photos
>     → Flickr search (only Creative Commons licensed photos)
>     → Any user's photostream (only if user has enabled download)

Comment: What about uploading?